# How can I mount an NFSv4 export with multiple IPs

Tags: linux, mount, nfs4, multipath, multi-homed

I have a Synology with 2 controllers exporting an NFSv4 share. The NFS export can be accessible via any of the 2 IPs (which are on different subnets). How on a CentOS/RHEL/Rocky Linux distro, can I mount the NFS export and have it multipath or know about both IPs going to the same mounted export? My goal is to achieve multipath redundancy in case one controller fails. In VMWare, when you add the NFS export as a datastore, I believe you just list the 2 IPs separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the multipathing feature in NFS 4.1 the server and the client need to support it. And for now only VMWare as a client supports NFS multipathing on the client side.

The best solution for your case is to use a cluster (HA) IP on the Synology. So the IP on your Synology will be available and you only need to configure one cluster IP on your clients.

Comment: Apparently all the HA IP config do not apply to the Synology model with 2 controllers built in. It has a disclaimer in  https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_can_I_modify_the_IP_and_Link_Aggregation_of_the_servers

and I have the SA3200D =(

Comment: Then you should configure failover with SHA as described here: https://global.synologydownload.com/download/Document/Software/UserGuide/Package/HighAvailability/All/enu/Synology_High_Availability_Guide_7_1_enu.pdf

Your NFS IPs will failover to the second controller if the first controller fails.